# AWS Multi-Part Upload error: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used the sample code from Amazon and it seems to work ok but then fails with the following error:

> The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against
>   our published schema

I think the ETags is required though commented out in doc (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html).  I have been struggling building this.

Code:
        // List to store upload part responses.
        List uploadResponses = new List();

```
    // 1. Initialize.
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = keyName
    };

    InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse = s3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);

    // 2. Upload Parts.
    long contentLength = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
    long partSize = 5 * (long)Math.Pow(2, 20); // 5 MB

    try
    {
        long filePosition = 0;
        for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++)
        {

            // Create request to upload a part.
            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = keyName,
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                PartNumber = i,
                PartSize = partSize,
                FilePosition = filePosition,
                FilePath = fileName
            };

            // Upload part and add response to our list.
            uploadResponses.Add(s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest));
            filePosition += partSize;
        }

        // Step 3: complete.
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = keyName,
            UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
        };

        CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse =
          s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);

        return "Complete";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was found that while the example code does not use PartETag it is necessary.  I added the following under the definition of UploadPartResponse:

```
List<PartETag> partETags = new List<PartETag>();
```

Then added the following after the uploadResponses.Add portion of code:

```
PartETag petag = new PartETag(s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest).PartNumber, s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest).ETag);
partETags.Add(petag);
```

Finally modified CompleteMultipartUploadRequest to the code below:

```
// Step 3: complete.
CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = fileTest, 
    UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
    PartETags = partETags
};
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to simply add the last line, instaed of creating a list an calling UploadPart twice:

```
 CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = keyName,
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                PartETags = uploadResponses.Select(part=>new PartETag(part.PartNumber,part.ETag)).ToList()
            };
```